# If longlines-mode is removed in new emacs, how can I soft-wrap the line around the column instead of window edge?

Tags: line-break, spacemacs

I'm now trying to switch from Vim to Spacemacs. It seems that `Longlines Mode` is the way to go in Emacs to soft-wrap the line around the column http://emacswiki.org/emacs/LineWrap. However it seems that this mode has been removed since Emacs 24.4 http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LongLines, in favor of `Visual Line Mode`, which soft-wraps the text around the window edge... Which is not exactly what I want. How am I able to get the functionality of longlines mode back? I see a longlines.el at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/longlines.el, should I just manually download the file and add it to Spacemacs configuration layer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. To emulate the behaviour of `longlines-mode`, use `visual-line-mode` in combination with the [visual-fill-column](https://github.com/joostkremers/visual-fill-column) package.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the package to go to. However now I'm unable to install it in Spacemacs... Guess I'll turn to somewhere else for help on package intallation.

Answer (score 2):

It has not been removed (yet).  It has been marked obsolete, which among other things implies that it is not autoloaded any more.

```
(require 'longlines)
(longlines-mode 1)
```

still works as before.

Comment: That's true. I guess I misunderstood the meaning of "obselete" here. Though isn't it quite weird that `longlines-mode` is able to softwrap by `fill column` while `visual-line-mode` is only able to soft wrap around the window, while the later is considered as a replacement for the previous? It actually looks like a loss of important functionality. `visual-fill-column` package messed up my `popwin` buffer so I couldn't really use it.